# How can I get my code to change the value in the popup?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, firefox-addon

I'm building or rather trying to build a Firefox Extension. When you click the button on the toolbar the popup opens up and the user enters in a number, the popup then counts down from that. However the popup doesn't show any value.

The Manifest.json file:

```
{

    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Timer",
    "version": "1.0",

    "description": "",
    "homepage_url": "",
    "icons": {
      "48": "icons/border-48.png"
    },

    "permissions": [
      "activeTab"
    ],

    "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "icons/border-48.png",
      "default_title": "Timer",
      "default_popup": "popup/pro.html"
    }

  }
```

The JavaScript:

```
    function timeInMinutesLeft(time){
      let timeSetByUser=(time*60);//converting to seconds
      let start=Date.now();  
      let elapsed = (Date.now() - start)/1000;//time elapsed in seconds
      let timeLeft = Math.round(timeSetByUser - elapsed)
      document.getElementById("timeLeft").innerHTML = timeLeft;
      return timeLeft;
    }
    function set(tabs) {
      let timesUp=False;
      let timeInput=document.getElementById('timerValue');
      let timeInputValue=timeInput.value();
      timeLeft = setInterval(timeInMinutesLeft(timeInputValue), 1000);
    }
```

The HTML:

```
<div id="popup-content">
        <h6 id=title></h6>
        <input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="60" id="timerValue">
        <p id="timeLeft"></p>
        <div class="set button">Timer</div>
    </div>
```

The timeOutput.value=timeLeft; doesn't seem to be outputting the time left to the popup in the toolbar.

Comment: have you tried timeOutput.innerHTML=

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that *duplicates the problem*. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions you almost always need to include your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML, and often webpage HTML/scripts. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't my code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the elementSelector is losing it's binding whenever it gets recreated upon changing the value, that's how the DOM operates. You need to let your scoped element be reachable from your interval like such:

```js
var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);

function myTimer() {
  var d = new Date();
  var t = d.toLocaleTimeString();
  document.getElementById("timeLeft").innerHTML = t;
}
```

```html
    
    
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="popup-content">
    <h6 id=title></h6>
    <input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="60" id="timerValue">
    <p id="timeLeft"></p>
    <div class="set button">Timer</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I added this:   document.getElementById("timeLeft").innerHTML = timeLeft;                     to the timeInMinutesLeft function and var myVar = setInterval(timeInMinutesLeft(), 1000);
but it doesn't seem to fix it.